# Show there exists precisely one number $\alpha$ where $0 \le \alpha < 210$ that solves the system of congruence equations.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show there exists precisely one number $\alpha$ where $0 \le \alpha < 210$ that solves the system of congruence equations:
>
> $x^2 + x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$
>
> $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 6$
>
> $x \equiv 1 \pmod 7$

I know $2$ is the only number $< 5$ solving $x^2 + x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $0, 1, 3, 4$ are numbers $< 6$ solving $x^2 \equiv a \pmod 6$ where $0 \le a < 6$.

So to sum up we know $x$ must satisfy the following criterion's: $[x]_5 = [2]_5$, $[x]_6 = [3]_6$ and $[x]_7 = [1]_7$.

I must also show that $x^2 - 6y^2 = 2$ has no solution $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem? And for your second question, think modulo $3$.

Comment: Yes, but how can I apply the CRT to quadratics ?

Comment: Are you sure that the second equality is correct? Doesn't seem to have any solutions.

Comment: I've corrected it.

Comment: Note that the first two equalities each have one solution (you can check by trying $x = 0,1,2,\ldots$). Then apply CRT.

Comment: Thank you, Arthur. And the last question, you solve by assuming $(x,y)$ is a solution, and then get the contradiction that $[x^2]_3 = [2]_3$ isn't solve-able, since equality $[x^2-6y^2]_k=[2]_k$ must hold for any $k \in \mathbb N$ ??

Comment: The result of `[(x,(x*x+x-1) \`mod\` 5,(x*x-3) \`mod\` 6) | x<-[1,8..209]]` is `[(1,1,4),(8,1,1),(15,4,0),(22,0,1),(29,4,4),(36,1,3),(43,1,4),(50,4,1),(57,0,0),(64,4,1),(71,1,4),(78,1,3),(85,4,4),(92,0,1),(99,4,0),(106,1,1),(113,1,4),(120,4,3),(127,0,4),(134,4,1),(141,1,0),(148,1,1),(155,4,4),(162,0,3),(169,4,4),(176,1,1),(183,1,0),(190,4,1),(197,0,4),(204,4,3)]`, so the only solution is $57$. Yes that defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "Yes that defeats the purpose of the exercise. ?" - And what are your triples showing ?

Comment: @user111854, the triples consist of $x$, the remainder of $x^2+x-1$ after division by $5$, and the remainder of $x^2-3$ after division by $6$. I restricted the calculation to the $x$ in the desired range that are congruent to $1$ modulo $7$. Hence solutions correspond to triples of the form $(x,0,0)$, and there is only one, namely $(57,0,0)$.  Of course this brute force solution is most probably not what whoever posed the question intended, but it is quite feasible, even by hand. So everyone should be able to find *a* solution to the problem, even if it is not a very good one.

Comment: Btw, that is [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell), and I typed it into [ghci](http://www.haskell.org/platform/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ You have already reduced the quadratic congruences to *equivalent* linear congruences, e.g. you proved that $\rm\ mod\ \color{#0A0}6\!:\ x^2\equiv 3\iff x\equiv 3.\:$ So replacing the quadratic congruences by their equivalent linear congruences  yields an equivalent system having linear form $\rm\ x \equiv a_k\pmod{ m_{k}},\ $ where the $\rm\:m_k = 5,6,7\:$are pairwise coprime. By [CRT (Chinese Remainder)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) there *exists* a solution which, further, is *unique* mod $\,5\cdot 6\cdot 7 = 210.\ \ $ **QED**

For the second part, you have already computed the $\rm\color{blue}{squares}$ mod $\,\color{#0a0}6,$ which do not include $\color{#c00}2$. What does this imply when you examine $\rm\,(mod\ \color{#0a0}6)$ your equation  $\rm\ \color{blue}{x^2} - \color{#0a0}6\,y^2\! = \color{#C00}2\ $

**Remark** $\ $ Note that you do not need to *compute* the solution. Rather, the problem requires only showing that there  *exists* a solution that is *unique* mod $\,210,\,$ which follows immediately by CRT.

Comment: Nice answer. For the second part, you just assume there is a solution and get a contradiction, since equality must be preserved on both sides of $[x^2-6y^2]_k = [2]_k$ for any $k$ ?

Comment: @user111854 Yes, that's what I mean by "examining the equation $\rm\,(mod\ 6).\,$" I chose the modulus $\, k=6\,$ (vs. the easier $\, k=3)\,$ because that allows one to immediately finish from the prior work in the first part (I presumed that the second part was meant to be connected to the first part).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:  adjusting to the edited Question

We can adopt the following method

$\displaystyle  x^2\equiv3\pmod6\iff x\equiv3\pmod6\ \ \  (1)$

$\displaystyle   x^2+x\equiv1\pmod5\implies 4x^2+4x\equiv4\pmod5\iff(2x+1)^2\equiv0$
$\displaystyle\iff 2x+1\equiv0\equiv x\equiv2\pmod5\  \ \ \ (2)$

$\displaystyle  x\equiv1\pmod7 \ \ \  \ (3)$

Then we can safely apply [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) on $(1),(2),(3)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry it should be $$x^2 \equiv 3 (\mod 6)$$ and not $$x^2 + x \equiv 3 (\mod 6)$$

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen, please find the edited vesrion

Answer (score 1):

We know $x^2 +x \equiv 1 (\mod 5)$ has solution $2 + 5k = [2]_5$ and $x^2 \equiv 3 (\mod 6)$ has solution $3+6k = [3]_6$ and $x \equiv 1 (\mod 7)$ has solution $1+7k = [1]_7$.

Also $\gcd(5,6,7) = 1$. So we have the following congruences:

$$X \equiv 2 (\mod 5)$$ $$X \equiv 3 (\mod 6)$$ $$X\equiv 1(\mod 7)$$

Solving these using the CRT we get $X = -363 \mod 210 = 57$ as a solution in range $0$ to (not including $210$).

To show $$x^2-6y^2 = 2$$ has not solution we assume $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2$ is a solution. Then $[x^2-6y^2]_k = [2]_k$ for any $k \in \mathbb N - \{0\}$ by equality. Letting $k=3$ we get $[x^2]_3 = [2]_3$ which has no solution for $x \in \mathbb Z$, a contradiction that $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2$ was a solution.